# Can't connect Visual Web Developer to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-connection

I had a perfectly fine, working database and website coming along, and for some reason out of the blue, I go to log in and I get the error:

> Cannot open database "BookDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user

And stack trace:

> > [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "BookDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user
> >     'GSCC-L10017\acallus'.]
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> >     exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5096342
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> >     SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> >     BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> >     stateObj) +2294
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
> >     enlistOK) +35
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
> >     serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
> >     TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +245
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
> >     serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
> >     SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
> >     TimeoutTimer timeout) +703
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
> >     owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString
> >     connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
> >     +195    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> >     identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
> >     String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
> >     redirectedUserInstance) +232
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> >     options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
> >     DbConnection owningConnection) +185
> >     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
> >     owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
> >     +33    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> >     owningObject) +524
> >     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> >     owningObject) +66
> >     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
> >     owningObject) +479
> >     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
> >     owningConnection) +108
> >     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
> >     outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
> >     System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context,
> >     Boolean revertImpersonate) +95
> >     System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String
> >     connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +206
> >     System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String
> >     username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String&
> >     password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32&
> >     failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
> >     Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime&
> >     lastActivityDate) +827
> >     System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String
> >     username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate,
> >     Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
> >     System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
> >     username, String password) +106
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs
> >     e) +60
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs
> >     e) +129    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +127
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs
> >     e) +101    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source,
> >     EventArgs args) +37
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> >     eventArgument) +167
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> >     eventArgument) +10
> >     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
> >     sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
> >     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> >     +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> >     +5563

I've tried absolutely everything I can find to fix this problem, and have come to find the following things:
 - The database will only connect to SQL Server Management Studio OR Visual Web Developer one at a time - I can never get it to work in both programs at the same time anymore.
 - Even when I have it connected to Visual Web Developer, I can still not actually do anything on my site which connects to the database (I get the above error).

I connect to my server instance through Windows Authentication, the database is located in the App_Data folder of my Website - I originally attached it to Management Studio.

My web.config is as follows:

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\IPT2012;Initial Catalog=BookDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've tried everything. Can someone please shed some light on this situation before I truly rip out my hair in frustration.

Comment: Which version/edition of Sql Server? Could you have accidentally put the database in single user mode?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 RC2. And I doubt it. Although, I think I may have done something to tw actual security properties of the file... I added my Windows Account to have security permissions of the actual database file (I forget the reason why)... Could this be the reason why? But then, I have tried creating new databases and it never works either.

Comment: I just came across this site: http://geekswithblogs.net/enriquelima/archive/2010/08/21/visual-web-developer-2010-and-sql-server-express-user-instances.aspx. I will give it a shot (considering it seems to describe my situation exactly) and get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string add User ID and Password attribute

```
<connectionStrings>
 <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\IPT2012;Initial Catalog=BookDatabase;Integrated Security=True; User ID = userName; Password = yourpassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Isn't this for if you aren't using Windows Authentication? And plus, that code has worked fine for a week (until now)... Thanks anyway.

Comment: The error occured bcz the database requires UserID and Password. May be you are currently login through windows authentication and the db requires sql server authentication